# How to fetch archived history from Chrome API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to list archived (90+ days) history URLs from Google Chrome using Chrome API.

I realised that it's probably impossible because the results have not been returned:

```js
let urlAmount = 0;
chrome.history.search(
{
  "text": "",
  "startTime": new Date(2018, 5, 14, 11, 0, 0).getTime(),
  "endTime": new Date(2018, 6, 14, 11, 0, 0).getTime()
},
function(historyItems)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; i++)
  {
    urlAmount++;
  }
});
```

As you can see I'm checking (2018.05.14 - 2018.06.14) time interval (it's more that 90 days ago from now).
`urlAmount` is 0 but for example (2019.01.14 - 2019.01.20) it's 100 (default max value is 100).

Is it possible to fetch such archived history this way?
If not what about Selenium automation approach?

Comment: You didn't clarify your question, so I thought you wanted the `urlAmount` value to be used inside the callback. If you want to use its value outside the callback `function(historyItems)`, you have to use another callback just to set a value to it or use a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

The `urlAmount` variable is incremented inside a callback. So you should move  its initialization to the callback `function(historyItems)`, right before the `for` loop.

The default value for `maxResults` is 100 if you don't use it, but you can set to it a higher value.